# Odoo issue : missing record does not exist or has been deleted

Tags: odoo

In Quotation => New

Select customer => Search more

result => Odoo Error : missing record does not exist or has been deleted

POST http://example.net/web/dataset/call_kw/res.partner/name_search 200 OK :

```
"Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/mnt/odoo-source/odoo/http.py", line 640, in _handle_exception
    return super(JsonRequest, self)._handle_exception(exception)
  File "/mnt/odoo-source/odoo/http.py", line 677, in dispatch
    result = self._call_function(**self.params)
  File "/mnt/odoo-source/odoo/http.py", line 333, in _call_function
    return checked_call(self.db, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/mnt/odoo-source/odoo/service/model.py", line 101, in wrapper
    return f(dbname, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/mnt/odoo-source/odoo/http.py", line 326, in checked_call
    result = self.endpoint(*a, **kw)
  File "/mnt/odoo-source/odoo/http.py", line 935, in __call__
    return self.method(*args, **kw)
  File "/mnt/odoo-source/odoo/http.py", line 506, in response_wrap
    response = f(*args, **kw)
  File "/mnt/odoo-source/addons/web/controllers/main.py", line 885, in call_kw
    return self._call_kw(model, method, args, kwargs)
  File "/mnt/odoo-source/addons/web/controllers/main.py", line 877, in _call_kw
    return call_kw(request.env[model], method, args, kwargs)
  File "/mnt/odoo-source/odoo/api.py", line 679, in call_kw
    return call_kw_model(method, model, args, kwargs)
  File "/mnt/odoo-source/odoo/api.py", line 664, in call_kw_model
    result = method(recs, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/mnt/odoo-source/odoo/addons/base/res/res_partner.py", line 681, in name_search
    return super(Partner, self).name_search(name, args, operator=operator, limit=limit)
  File "/mnt/odoo-source/odoo/models.py", line 1600, in name_search
    return self._name_search(name, args, operator, limit=limit)
  File "/mnt/odoo-source/odoo/models.py", line 1615, in _name_search
    return recs.sudo(access_rights_uid).name_get()
  File "/mnt/odoo-source/odoo/addons/base/res/res_partner.py", line 586, in name_get
    name = name + "\n" + partner._display_address(without_company=True)
  File "/mnt/odoo-source/odoo/addons/base/res/res_partner.py", line 781, in _display_address
    address_format = self.country_id.address_format or \
  File "/mnt/odoo-source/odoo/fields.py", line 866, in __get__
    value = record._cache[self]
  File "/mnt/odoo-source/odoo/models.py", line 5562, in __getitem__
    return value.get() if isinstance(value, SpecialValue) else value
  File "/mnt/odoo-source/odoo/fields.py", line 48, in get
    raise self.exception
MissingError: (u'Enregistrement inexistant ou d\xe9truit.', None)
"
```

I'm stuck with this issue. Anyone know what could i do ?

Comment: Show us your custom code

Comment: There is no custom code. I think one user could have deleted some records. I'm browsing the database looking for broken links. Not sure i'm on the way to solve this.

Comment: I couldn't export my partner list so I have found some missing link between some partners and the unique pricelist existing. So i have added the missing records into "ir_property" table. Now i can export my customer list but the issue is still here. Working on it

Comment: Same for users cause there was leads referencing missing stages, I have deleted them but the issue is still here

Comment: Pro Tip: This issue also presents itself if you delete the default tax rates (15%) without first changing the website settings to a new tax rate. You will not be able to get back into the settings because it references the default rate (15%) you deleted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is solved. 
"Country_id" field in "res_partner" table was referencing an unexisting country in "res_country table".